# Can't connect to Poloniex

Tags: c#, poloniex

I'm trying to connect to Poloniex. To connect, I'm using WynthShop and this code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var channelFactory = new DefaultWampChannelFactory();
        var channel = channelFactory.CreateJsonChannel("wss://api.poloniex.com", "realm1");
        channel.Open().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var tickerSubject = channel.RealmProxy.Services.GetSubject("ticker");

        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        using (var subscr = tickerSubject.Subscribe(evt =>
        {
            var currencyPair = evt.Arguments[0].Deserialize<string>();
            var last = evt.Arguments[1].Deserialize<decimal>();
            Console.WriteLine($"Currencypair: {currencyPair}, Last: {last}");
        }))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately I get the error "Unable to connect to the remote server". 
Maybe someone knows how to solve the problem with the connection. Also I tried to use the following code, but also fails to connect:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var channelFactory = new DefaultWampChannelFactory();
        var channel = channelFactory.CreateJsonChannel("wss://api.poloniex.com", "realm1");

        Func<Task> connect = async () =>
        {
            //await Task.Delay(30000);

            await channel.Open();

            var tickerSubject = channel.RealmProxy.Services.GetSubject("ticker");

            var subscription = tickerSubject.Subscribe(evt =>
                {
                    var currencyPair = evt.Arguments[0].Deserialize<string>();
                    var last = evt.Arguments[1].Deserialize<decimal>();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Currencypair: {currencyPair}, Last: {last}");
                },
                ex => {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Oh no! {ex}");
                });
        };

        WampChannelReconnector reconnector =
            new WampChannelReconnector(channel, connect);

        reconnector.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the inner exception ? 
For me it was the SSL/TLS version i'm supporting as the client

Answer (score 0):

I create the websocket myself specifying the SSL/TLS versions i can support

```
 public void Connect()
 {
        _channel = new DefaultWampChannelFactory().ConnectToRealm(_realm)
            .WebSocketTransport(prtcl => CreateWebSocket(prtcl, _url))
            .JsonSerialization()
            .Build();
        //.CreateJsonChannel(_url, _realm);
        //_channel.RealmProxy.

        _channel.RealmProxy.Monitor.ConnectionBroken += (sender, args) =>
        {
            _logger.WriteError(string.Format("ConnectionError -> From connection error event WssUrl : {0} , Realm : {1}", _url, _realm), new ArgumentException(args.Details != null ? args.Details.Message : "NO Details" ));
        };

         _channel.RealmProxy.Monitor.ConnectionError += (sender, args) =>
         {
             _logger.WriteError(string.Format("ConnectionError -> From connection error event WssUrl : {0} , Realm : {1}",_url,_realm), args.Exception);
         };

         _channel.RealmProxy.Monitor.ConnectionEstablished += (sender, args) =>
         {
             string info = string.Format("from ConnectionEstablished event -> WssUrl : {0} , Realm : {1}", _url, _realm);
             OnConnected(info);
         };

        _reconnector = new WampChannelReconnector(_channel, ConnectInternal);
        _reconnector.Start();
    }

    private static WebSocket CreateWebSocket(string subprotocolName, string serverAddress)
    {         
        WebSocket result = new WebSocket(serverAddress,
            subprotocolName, null, null, string.Empty, string.Empty, WebSocketVersion.None,null,SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12, 4096);

        result.AutoSendPingInterval = 10;

        return result;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

When you read the [API doc](https://poloniex.com/support/api/), you can read:

> Push API
>
> The best way to get public data updates on markets is via the push API, which pushes live ticker, order book, trade, and Trollbox updates over WebSockets **using the WAMP protocol**. In order to use the push API, connect to wss://api.poloniex.com and subscribe to the desired feed.

WAMP =  The **W**eb **A**pplication **M**essaging **P**rotocol

So you will have to chose a C# lib compatible with WAMP protocol, you may take a [look here](http://wamp-proto.org/implementations/) to find an comptable implementation.

In your case you may use [WampSharp](https://github.com/Code-Sharp/WampSharp)  which is compatible with C#