# How to send a command when connecting started in WampSharp

Tags: c#, wampsharp

I encountered with this problem [Can't connect to Poloniex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134929/cant-connect-to-poloniex)
. I think I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436264/reading-messages-on-poloniex-trollbox-with-python-autbahn-or-other-socket-module/43319080#43319080). I need to send a command when I open connecting. Like this.

```
from websocket import create_connection
import json

ws = create_connection("wss://api2.poloniex.com:443")
ws.send('{"command" : "subscribe", "channel" : 1001}')

while True:
    result = ws.recv()
    json_result = json.loads(result)
    if len(json_result) >= 3:
        print(json_result)

ws.close()
```

But it code for Python. How can I made it in WampSharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WampSharp is a library for the WAMP protocol. The code you attached does not use the WAMP protocol, but a different custom WebSocket subprotocol. Therefore this service can not be consumed using a WAMP library.